# How do inject properties or environment variables into my Maven plugin testcase?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I've created a Maven plugin using [AbstractMojo](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/maven-plugin-api/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/AbstractMojo.html) and I'm trying to test it.

I'm using the [maven-plugin-testing-harness](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/getting-started/index.html) to do the testing and I'm having problems with injecting values for my plugin parameters.

I have the following pom.xml file (`src/test/resources/pom.xml`) for testing:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.vodori.pepper.docker.vm.unit</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Test VMStarter</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vodori.common</groupId>
                <artifactId>pepper-docker-vm</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dockerSnapshotSite>pepper-demo-site</dockerSnapshotSite>
                    <dockerSnapshotVersion>3.6.11</dockerSnapshotVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My Mojo looks like this (at the top):

```
public abstract class VMPlugin extends AbstractMojo {

    /**
     * Docker location
     */
    @Parameter(required = true, property = "docker.path", defaultValue = "${env.DOCKER_LOCATION}")
    String dockerPath;

    public void setDockerPath(String dockerPath) {
        this.dockerPath = dockerPath;
    }

    /**
     * Docker VM Site name
     */
    @Parameter(required = true, property = "docker.snapshot.site")
    String dockerSnapshotSite;

    /**
     * Version of Docker snapshot
     */
     @Parameter (required = true, property="docker.snapshot.version")
    String dockerSnapshotVersion;
```

I'm using the [@MojoRule](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing-archives/LATEST/maven-plugin-testing-harness/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/testing/MojoRule.html) approach for testing and my setup method looks like this:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    vmStarter = (VMStarter) rule.lookupMojo( "start-docker-vm", "src/test/resources/pom.xml" );
    assertNotNull(vmStarter);
}
```

I use the setter for some of my testcases (the ones that test *bad* docker locations), but for my good path testing, I want to rely on the environment variable `DOCKER_LOCATION` for populating. However, for some reason, `dockerPath` is just showing up as `null`. It's as if the `defaultValue` is being ignored.

I've tried dumping `System.getEnv()` onto STDERR and I can see that `DOCKER_LOCATION` is *indeed* set.

What am I missing here? Why isn't my `@Parameter` getting populated correctly?

Comment: A `defaultValue` should be a hard coded value for such things like a path in your case. If you really like to use an environment value it has to be coded in your mojo. So you just omit a default value and check within the execution method if it has been set or not and use an approriate value. I can not recomment to use environments values for such things. I would suggest to define some hard coded value (default) and otherwise the user needs to write that configuration element in the pom. The `defaultValue` isn't calculated in the way to get environment values into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get the syntax `defaultValue = "${env.DOCKER_LOCATION}"` from?

`env.*` is a [property](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html) and *"you can use Maven properties in a pom.xml file or in any resource that is being processed by the Maven Resource plugin’s filtering features."*

`default-value` requires an [expression](https://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html).

[Guide to Developing Java Plugins, Introduction](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html) mentions: *"(more can be found in the "Parameter Expressions" document)"*. <s>But i didn't find such a document so far.</s> Thx @khmarbaise: [org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.html).

[`help:expressions`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/expressions-mojo.html) doesn't show `${env}` with my Maven 3.2.1.

Though it's my experience that at least some, if not all, of the linked docs are not up-to-date and withhold latest enhancements.

Possible explanation from a program logic point of view: If a default value has to be set outside the scope of a program it can't be considered a default value. In the sense of Maven's [Convention Over Configuration](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/installation-sect-conventionConfiguration.html).

EDIT: Added link to *Expressions API documentation*.

Comment: The expression document can be found here: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.html The `expression` is only valid for `maven-plugin-plugin` version 2 (Maven 2). BTW: If you find such things which are not correct/not update to date why not filing in a issue or give a message on the users mailing list?

Comment: `DOCKER_LOCATION=demonstrate mvn help:evaluate` does show that Maven can evaluate `${env.DOCKER_LOCATION}`

Comment: The document here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html#Parameters lays out `defaultValue`

Comment: However, the link provided by @khmarbaise demonstrates that `{$env.*}` is not supported for `defaultValue`

Comment: @Gerold Broser The link which missed on the guide has been added (give some time untill synchronization).

Comment: @khmarbaise Thx for the link. Though I don't consider this being a _document_ (with sections, paragraphs etc.). It's good, however, that this API document_ation_ provides the information in question. Why no issue/message? To be honest, whenever I needed a particular information I found it somewhere else after a bit of searching (yes, often on SO :-). And in that very moment I always was in the middle of a project that needed to be done. After finishing it I didn't think of the missing info here and there any more. But maybe you gave me the initial kick that lets me consider this in future. :-)

Comment: It would be great to get a short message on the users list just the link to the page and what you missed would help, so someone (may be i) can fix it. Otherwise it's not possible. Thanks for your help and answers. The reason why it's a not a document. Simple. We are developers as well and don't like writing documentations. The link is of course generated from written code (makes it easier).